# Halt app execution immediately

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

Is there a way to halt execution, somewhat like SIG_ABRT, but *immediately*, even if we're not on the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Core Foundation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635/CFInternal.h) has a macro `HALT` that should do the trick, if you *really*, **really** think it's necessary to do this:

```
#if defined(__ppc__)
    #define HALT do {asm __volatile__("trap"); kill(getpid(), 9); } while (0)
#elif defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__)
    #if defined(__GNUC__)
        #define HALT do {asm __volatile__("int3"); kill(getpid(), 9); } while (0)
    #elif defined(_MSC_VER)
        #define HALT do { DebugBreak(); abort(); } while (0)
    #else
        #error Compiler not supported
    #endif
#endif
#if defined(__arm__)
    #define HALT do {asm __volatile__("bkpt 0xCF"); kill(getpid(), 9); } while (0)
#endif
```

Comment: These are nice, but have some problems. The asm instructions are essentially breakpoint generators, which is great if you expect to have a debugger attached, but maybe not what you want otherwise (ie: on windows it will trigger a crash/debug dialog by default).  Oh, the MSC one calling abort() is ok, but still has more infrastructure/cruft than TerminateProcess()

Comment: @Joe: I don't think doing this in any fashion is a good idea at all. CF only uses this macro for fatal errors. The right answer to the question, as far as I'm concerned is "Yes, but you shouldn't". Note that I didn't write these, and that they are in active use.

Comment: That does the trick nicely! Thank you! @Joe: breakpoint generators is *perfect* for my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Macintosh app, "`[[NSApp sharedApplication] terminate: self]`" will work.

On an iPhone, you can even do "`exit(-1)`", but Apple will ***NOT*** accept any apps that abruptly or in any way terminate other than the user killing the app themselves.  [Here is a related question with some useful answers for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021118/how-to-close-an-application-programmatically-when-the-user-taps-on-a-button).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't like exit() or _exit() which have some cleanup semantics, you can go with s

```
#include <signal.h>

kill( getpid(), SIGKILL );
```

And if you are on windows (assuming not since 'cocoa' tagged), you can use

```
TerminateProcess( GetCurrentProcess(), -1 );
```

This is all pretty harsh, so things should be pretty bad to do this.