# how to close application in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close an application programmatically when the user taps on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021118/how-to-close-an-application-programmatically-when-the-user-taps-on-a-button)

I haven't seen any close option in IOS application, Users have to close it from the home button. I want to put the closing option in program, can some body suggest the line of code that I can integrate in my application to close a program. Such as in Action Button.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this as you would have to take care of the release of allocated objects (if it's not an ACL project), etc. Stick with the home button IMHO.

Comment: @Vladimir, sorry for re-asking, I first checked in the stackoverflow and google, did not find the answer(platform in the previously asked question was not provided), so I asked it again....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an iOS application quit goes against Apple's UI guidelines. If you submit an application with this feature to the App Store it will get rejected.